# Won't connect to scriptcam server

Tags: javascript, flash, camera, ip-camera

I have put scriptcam in to 2 host server. Bluehost and Hostinger and still get the same result, as follow: (console check via chrome web developer tool)

```
ScriptCam version 1.4.0 booting...
Running on Flash PlugIn (WIN 11,6,602,180)
Adding global error handler
Adding right mousehandler
Retrieving flashvars
id:webcam
zoomChat:1
fileReady:function fileReady(qfileName) {
                //$('#recorder').hide();
                $('#message').html('Please wait for the file conversion to finish...');
                waitForMovie(qfileName);
            }
zoom:1
skewX:0
filename:testfile
rotate:0
noFlashFound:<p>You need <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Adobe Flash Player 11.4</a> to use this software.<br/>Please click on the link to download the installer.</p>
flip:0
cornerRadius:0
width:550
setVolume:function setVolume(value) {
            $('#currentVolume').val(value);
            alert('Current Volume is ' + value);
            $.scriptcam.changeVolume(50);
            }
chatWindow:chatWindow
height:320
maximumTime:30
onError:function onError(errorId,errorMsg) {
                alert(errorMsg);
            }
path:scriptcam/
connected:function showRecord() {
                alert('Connect !!!');
                $( "#recordStartButton" ).attr( "disabled", false );
                //$('#b-screen').fadeIn(500);
                //$('#start-btn').attr( "disabled", false );
            }
skewY:0
timeLeft:function timeLeft(value) {
                $('input#timeLeft').val(value);
            }
Correcting video dimensions
Correcting scale
Drawing masks in memory
Starting ZXing
Setting AMF3 encoding
Init H264 encoder
h264Settings: Video codec used for compression: H264Avc
h264Settings: Level used for H.264/AVC encoding: 3
h264Settings: Profile used for H.264/AVC encoding: baseline
h264Settings: Bandwidth: 0
h264Settings: FPS: -1
h264Settings: Keyframe interval: 30
h264Settings: Quality: 90
Adding camera
Setting camera size to width: 550 height:320
Hardware acceleration used for camera: STAGEVIDEO
Hardware acceleration is available
License file loaded
Camera: Bandwidth: 0
Camera: Current FPS: 0
Camera: FPS: 30
Camera: Keyframe Interval: 30
Camera: Quality: 90
```

While if I take a look at their website in demo for recording camera, i see this: (console check via chrome web developer tool)

```
ScriptCam version 1.4.0 booting...
Running on Flash PlugIn (WIN 11,6,602,180)
Adding global error handler
Adding right mousehandler
Retrieving flashvars
cornerColor:e3e5e2
id:webcam
cornerRadius:20
timeLeft:function timeLeft(value) {
                $('#timeLeft').val(value);
            }
skewX:0
onError:function onError(errorId,errorMsg) {
                alert(errorMsg);
            }
skewY:0
fileName:demo430142
rotate:0
promptWillShow:function promptWillShow() {
                alert('A security dialog will be shown. Please click on ALLOW.');
            }
noFlashFound:<p>You need <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Adobe Flash Player 11.4</a> to use this software.<br/>Please click on the link to download the installer.</p>
width:320
connected:function showRecord() {
                $( "#recordStartButton" ).attr( "disabled", false );
            }
flip:0
height:240
onWebcamReady:function onWebcamReady(cameraNames,camera,microphoneNames,microphone,volume) {
                $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );
                $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", volume );
                $.each(cameraNames, function(index, text) {
                    $('#cameraNames').append( $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text) )
                }); 
                $('#cameraNames').val(camera);
                $.each(microphoneNames, function(index, text) {
                    $('#microphoneNames').append( $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text) )
                }); 
                $('#microphoneNames').val(microphone);
            }
path:
showMicrophoneErrors:false
chatWindow:chatWindow
fileReady:function fileReady(fileName) {
                $('#recorder').hide();
                $('#message').html('Please wait for the file conversion to finish...');
                waitForMovie(fileName);
            }
zoom:1
setVolume:function setVolume(value) {
                value=parseInt(32 * value / 100) + 1;
                for (var i=1; i < value; i++) {
                    $('#LedBar' + i).css('visibility','visible');
                }
                for (i=value; i < 33; i++) {
                    $('#LedBar' + i).css('visibility','hidden');
                }
            }
zoomChat:1
Correcting video dimensions
Correcting scale
Drawing masks in memory
Starting ZXing
Setting AMF3 encoding
Init H264 encoder
h264Settings: Video codec used for compression: H264Avc
h264Settings: Level used for H.264/AVC encoding: 3
h264Settings: Profile used for H.264/AVC encoding: baseline
h264Settings: Bandwidth: 0
h264Settings: FPS: -1
h264Settings: Keyframe interval: 30
h264Settings: Quality: 90
Adding camera
Setting camera size to width: 320 height:240
Hardware acceleration used for camera: STAGEVIDEO
Hardware acceleration is available
GET https://www.scriptcam.com/scriptcam.lic 404 (Not Found) demo_2.cfm:804
License could not be found
Camera: Bandwidth: 0
Camera: Current FPS: 0
Camera: FPS: 30
Camera: Keyframe Interval: 30
Camera: Quality: 90
Connecting to server
The page at https://www.scriptcam.com/demo_2.cfm displayed insecure content from http://europe.scriptcam.com:443/fcs/ident2.
 (program):1
POST http://europe.scriptcam.com:443/fcs/ident2 404 (Not Found) europe.scriptcam.com:443/fcs/ident2:1
The page at https://www.scriptcam.com/demo_2.cfm displayed insecure content from http://europe.scriptcam.com:443/open/1.
 (program):1
POST http://europe.scriptcam.com:443/open/1 404 (Not Found) europe.scriptcam.com:443/open/1:1
conectionOK
connectionOK-connect
connectionOK-connect-past
ncstatusevent fired
NetConnection.Connect.Success
NetConnection connected with protocol rtmp, proxy type none, connected proxy type none
```

If you see, the page i upload is their demo2.html which I believe has all the same setup as their demo page in their website. Their's connecting while mine not, am i doing something wrong?! Is there anyone have experience using scriptcam (version 1.40)?! Or do anyone have a better suggestion for Javascript Webcam Flash Lib?!

Any suggestion would mostly appreciated...

Thanks in advance,
Arung Isyadi

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the js code:

```
function fileReady(fileName) {
                $('#recorder').hide();
                $('#message').html('This file is now dowloadable for five minutes over &lt;a href='+fileName+'"&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;.');

[...]
```

Which uploads the file to webcam servers.

The error is in the href value.

Replace: `href='+fileName+'"`

With: `href='+fileName+'`.

(delete the last ")